# Export Ionic calendar to google calendar

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-calendar-api

so i made a calendar app that displays a list of events on a given date using ionic2 calendar but i want to export the events to the native calendar on android.
is There any docs that allows me to understand on how to implement such feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this ionic-native plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/calendar

From this github project: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

When you import the plugin in your module, then use this way:

```
    constructor(private calendar: Calendar) { }

    yourEvent(){
//check permission on android
     this.calendar.hasReadWritePermission().then((rta)=>{
          if (!rta){
            this.calendar.requestReadWritePermission();
            return;
          }
          this.calendar.createEventInteractively(title,location,otherNotes,startDate,endDate).then(
            (msg) => { console.log("msg "+JSON.stringify(msg)); },
            (err) => { console.log("err "+err); }


    );
    });
}
```

Hope it helps!